# "pyuic5" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

После переустановки Windows я не могу установить и использовать библиотеку pyuic5, нужную для преобразования QT.ui файлов в файлы .py.
До переустановки Windows у меня стаяла не самая актуальная версия python, но сейчас я установил Python 10. Я думал что моя проблема связана с тем что разработчик pyuic5 ещё не поддерживает последнюю версию Python, но после отката до Python 9, ничего не изменилось.
При попытки запустить ранее(до переустановки Windows) работающие команды я вижу ошибку:

```
"pyuic5" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

Я пробовал прописывать новые пути в переменных средах Windows с учётом того куда на моём компьютере были размещены папки "Scripts" для python, как для одной версии python так и для другой. При чём python 10 расположен по очень длинному и странному пути, но такой путь был выбран автоматически при установке я ничего не менял, вот эти пути:
Pyithon10:
c:\users\user\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\Scripts
Python9:
c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\

При чём в папках с этими путями располагаются только файлы pip.exe нескольких версий, но pyuic5.exe там нет.

При попытке повторно установить пакет сообщается что он уже установлен, и сообщается следующий адрес установки для Python10 (для Python9 такой же только с соответствующим путём установки )
c:\users\user\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (0.0.1)

по этому пути нет исполняемых файлов pyuic5, но есть папка pyuic5_tool-0.0.1.dist-info в которой находится несколько других файлов судя по всему с какой то информацией о пакете. Я так же пробовал указывать этот путь в путях переменных сред Windows, результата это не дало.

В конечном счёте я ни как не могу использовать pyuic5 и не знаю как решить свою проблему. Прилагаю  небольшой лог командной строки одной из последних попыток что то сделать, для наглядности:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1826]
(c) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation). Все права защищены.

C:\Users\user>pyuic5 -x DS_start_menu.ui -o "f:\Work area\KKI\Code\menus\pyqt_files\start_menu\DS_start_menu.py"
"pyuic5" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

C:\Users\user>pyuic5
"pyuic5" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

C:\Users\user>pyuic5 -x DS_start_menu.ui -o "f:\Work area\KKI\Code\menus\pyqt_files\start_menu\DS_start_menu.py"
"pyuic5" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

C:\Users\user>pip install pyuic5-tool
Requirement already satisfied: pyuic5-tool in c:\users\user\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (0.0.1)

C:\Users\user>pip install pyuic5-tool
Requirement already satisfied: pyuic5-tool in c:\users\user\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (0.0.1)

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.2.1 -> 22.2.2
[notice] To update, run: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip

C:\Users\user>pyuic5
"pyuic5" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

C:\Users\user>pyuic5 -x DS_start_menu.ui -o "f:\Work area\KKI\Code\menus\pyqt_files\start_menu\DS_start_menu.py"
"pyuic5" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

C:\Users\user>pyuic5 -x DS_start_menu.ui -o "f:\Work area\KKI\Code\menus\pyqt_files\start_menu\DS_start_menu.py"C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe install pyuic5-tool
"pyuic5" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

C:\Users\user>C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe install pyuic5-tool
Requirement already satisfied: pyuic5-tool in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (0.0.1)
WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 22.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

C:\Users\user>c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pyuic5_tool-0.0.1.dist-in pyuic5 -x DS_start_menu.ui -o "f:\Work area\KKI\Code\menus\pyqt_files\start_menu\DS_start_menu.py"
"c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pyuic5_tool-0.0.1.dist-in" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

Comment: Игорь Платонов, почему вы никак не реагируете на ответы, которые вам предоставляются?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил проблемы. Она заключалась в том что для корректной работы этого скрипта необходимо установить библиотеку PyQT5 в Windows. До этого она была установлена у меня в виртуальной среде проекта. Я не знал что этот скрипт требует такой установки, и об этом ни где не написано.